# Python3 preventing nested list and show position/index of values in list

Tags: python, indexing, nested

As the title suggest, i'm getting a nested list from splitting twice.

" ".join didn't help with this problem.
I also can't figure out how to print position of a word in the list.

The goal is to split id user text words on tab(which works) and print the words with their position in a list.

```
import sys
def main():
    olist = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        i,u,t,w = line.split('\t')

        olist.append(w.split())
        print(olist)
        for num,name in enumerate(olist):
            print(num, name)
```

output print(olist):

```
[['RT', '@AfshinEllian1', ':', 'Kennelijk', 'vinden', 'ze', 'daar', 'aan', 'die', 'gezellige', 'tafel', 'normaal', 'dat', 'steltje', 'barbaren', 'onze', 'grondwettelijke', 'rechten', 'bedreigen', '.', 'Zouden', 'we', 'ook', 'voor', 'andere', 'buitenwettelijke', 'dreigingen', 'moeten', 'capituleren', '?', 'Wat', 'een', 'door', 'ons', 'gesubsidieerde', 'domheid', '!', '#laatop1', '#cartoonwedstrijd']]
```

output print(num, name):

```
0 ['RT', '@AfshinEllian1', ':', 'Kennelijk', 'vinden', 'ze', 'daar', 'aan', 'die', 'gezellige', 'tafel', 'normaal', 'dat', 'steltje', 'barbaren', 'onze', 'grondwettelijke', 'rechten', 'bedreigen', '.', 'Zouden', 'we', 'ook', 'voor', 'andere', 'buitenwettelijke', 'dreigingen', 'moeten', 'capituleren', '?', 'Wat', 'een', 'door', 'ons', 'gesubsidieerde', 'domheid', '!', '#laatop1', '#cartoonwedstrijd']
```

Desired output =

```
RT [0]
@AfshinEllian1 [1]
: [2]
Kennelijk [3]
```

etc

Comment: Can you please show some example of your desired output?

Comment: Since there's only one item in your nesting, why not simply switch to `enumerate(olist[0])` ?  We're not sure what output you expect from this, and you neglected to supply proper input.

Comment: Added desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this line:

```
  olist.append(w.split())
```

is not doing what you want.  You need to extend the list instead:

```
  olist.extend(w.split())
```

which joins two lists.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to split it twice, simply print it directly via:

```
import sys

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for num, name in enumerate(line.split("\t")):
            print("{} [{}]".format(name.strip(), num))

main()

# next line is input line
This    is  a   test

# and the output for it ...
This [0]
is [1]
a [2]
test [3]
```

If you want to have ongoing numbering, you can also use this code. Here you can simply use the `+`-operator which will concat your lists which is probably what you want.

```
def main():
    olist = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        olist += [name for name in line.split("\t")]
        for num, name in enumerate(olist):
            print("{} [{}]".format(name.strip(), num))
```

The used `.strip()`-method is simply cosmetic, because sys.stdin will also catch line separator.